# ($\oplus$, $\otimes$) is a semiring. If $\otimes$ = +, what are the possible operators $\oplus$?

Tags: semirings

Assume that ($\oplus$, $\otimes$) is a semiring over the non-negative reals.

If $\otimes$ is +, what are the possible operators for $\oplus$?

So far I have proven that `max` and `softmax` (`logsumexp`) are solutions. Can we characterize all possible $\oplus$?

I'd also appreciate references to relevant papers.

Comment: Another solution is $x \oplus y = \log_b(b^x + b^y)$, and I think this would characterize all differentiable solutions (if not, at least analytic).

Comment: What is your definition of a semiring? As far as I can see, none of the examples have an additive unit element, which is part of the standard definition.

Comment: Or a multiplicative unit, for that matter, unless you mean "positive" to include 0.

Comment: Edit: replaced `positive` with `non-negative` and removed `min` solution. Now 0 is the additive and multiplicative unit.

Comment: @james.nixon any ideas for how I could prove that your solution (which is what I'm calling softmax) is the only differentiable solution?

Comment: If $0$ is the additive unit, we are required to have $0 \otimes x = 0$, right?  That is $0 + x = 0$ ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiring

Comment: A previous version of this question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/244963/is-the-only-semiring-over-the-positive-reals was closed by voters and then deleted by OP.

Comment: Please don't delete and then repost questions. That's a site violation.

Comment: @rafaelcosman If $f(x,y) = x \oplus y$ is differentiable in $x$ and $y$ then by def $f(x,y) + c = f(x + c, y+c)$. Taking $F(x,y) = e^{f(\log(x),\log(y))}$ then $F(x,y) \cdot c = F(cx,cy)$. If i'm not mistaken the only differentiable solution to $c F(x,y) = F(cx,cy)$,  $F(x,y) = F(y,x)$ and $F(x,F(y,z)) = F(F(x,y),z)$ is $F(x,y) = \sqrt[r]{x^r + y^r}$, and therefore $x \oplus y = \log_b(b^{x} +b^{y} )$ with $r = \frac{1}{\log(b)}$. QED.

Comment: oops I meant $r = log(b)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll give two answers. The first one just echoes the comments and saying that there are no such semirings, and the other saying that `max` gives the only continuous such semiring, if you take a nonstandard definition of semiring.

The standard definition of a (commutative) semiring is a set $R$ equipped with two operations $\otimes$ and $\oplus$, so that $(R,\otimes)$ and $(R,\oplus)$ are commutative monoids, so that $\otimes$ distributes over $\oplus$, and so that the unit of $\oplus$ annihilates $R$ under $\otimes$. I focus on the commutative case because you always want $\otimes$ to be addition, which is commutative.

Let $R$ denote the non-negative reals.

---

It's basically been pointed out in the comments that with this definition, there can be no such semiring structure on $R$ with addition as $\otimes$. This is because of the annihilation condition. Let $e$ be the unit of $\oplus$; then $e+a=e$ for all $a$ in $R$, which is not possible.

---

Next, drop the annihilation condition.  I'll show that `max` is the only continuous choice for $\oplus$ in this less restrictive definition. I will not assume that the additive unit is $0$. Note that choosing `softmax` for $\oplus$ (and addition for $\otimes$) does not yield a semiring structure on $R$ with this definition because $\oplus$ does not have an identity element.

First, note that $a + (0\oplus 0) = (a + 0) \oplus (a+0) = a\oplus a$ for all $a$ by distributivity. This is true for the additive unit so $(0\oplus 0)=0$ and thus $(a\oplus a)=a$ for all $a$.

Then define $f(a)= 0\oplus a$. Using distributivity, $(b\oplus (a+b))= f(a)+b$ for all $a$ and $b$. So $\oplus$ is totally determined by $f$.

By associativity of $\oplus$, we have $f(a) = 0\oplus a=(0\oplus 0)\oplus a=0\oplus (0\oplus a)=f(f(a))$, so $f$ is a retract. Decompose $R$ as $F\sqcup G$ where $a$ is in $F$ if $f(a)=a$.

If $G$ is empty, then $(b\oplus (a+b))=a+b=\max\{a,a+b\}$. This gives the answer of `max` for $\oplus$ that we already know. Then instead we can assume that $G$ is nonempty. Now let $z$ be the infimum of $G$. $F$ is closed and contains $0$ so $z\in F$. Then $(z\oplus 2z) = z + (0\otimes z)= 2z$ by distributivity. But then by associativity

$$2z = z\oplus 2z = (0\oplus z)\oplus 2z = 0\oplus (z\oplus 2z)= 0\oplus 2z = f(2z)$$ so $2z\in F$.

Now assume that $f$ is continuous. We will derive a contradiction. First suppose $a\in G$ and $b\in F$ with $a < b$. Then since $f(0)=0$ and $f(b)=b$, by the intermediate value theorem there is some $c$ with $f(c)=a$. But this implies $f(a)=f^2(c)=f(c)=a$, a contradiction since $a\in G$. Then we have shown that if $a\in G$ then all $b>a$ are also in $G$. In particular, if $z>0$ then $2z$ is in both $F$ (by the explicit calculation above) and $G$ (by this paragraph, by the definition of infimum), a contradiction.

The only remaining possibility is $\inf G=0$. But then the connectedness of $F$ implies that $F=\{0\}.$ But in this case, since $f(R)=F$, necessarily $f(R)=0$ which implies that $a\oplus (a+b)= a = \min\{a,a+b\}$. But $\min$ does not have a unit in $R$.

---

Maybe this can be modified to show that in the case that one also drops the assumption that $\oplus$ have a unit, that `min` and `softmax` are the only other continuous options. I'll leave that to someone else.

Answer (score 3):

I'll post my comment here. If $f(x,y)=x\oplus y$ and $f(x,y)$ is differentiable in $x$ and $y$ then $f(x,y) = \log_b(b^x + b^y)$. (I'm ignoring that $x \oplus y$ has no identity element (which would be $-\infty$ ad hoc)).

by def $f(x,y)+c=f(x+c,y+c)$. Taking $F(x,y)=e^{f(log(x),log(y))}$ then $F(x,y)⋅c=F(cx,cy)$.

Taking associativity and commutivity in to consideration; if i'm not mistaken the only differentiable solution to $cF(x,y)=F(cx,cy)$, $F(x,y)=F(y,x)$ and $F(x,F(y,z))=F(F(x,y),z)$ is $F(x,y)=\sqrt[r
]{x^r+y^r}$, and therefore $x \oplus y = \log_b(b^x+b^y)$ with $r = \log(b)$.
QED

$r$ can then be found for arbitrary $\oplus$ by plugging in values.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there is no nice and explicit characterization.

You can take a universal-algebraic approach: start with the set of positive reals, and form the term algebra using the two operations.  Then form the equivalence relation that "defines" times, using relations like 1/2 "times" 2/3 is identified with 7/6. Now you have a quotient by this relation which forms the semigroup of the augmented set under times, and you introduce further relationships that are the semiring identities.  The resulting quotient S will still be "larger than the reals , but now you take any quotient of S that does not identify two reals and you have a sample semiring with your definition of times.

There may also be a clone-theoretic approach that may yield an alternative description, but I don't see such a description being useful.  It may become useful to describe subsets of such functions, e.g. those that are continuous or order-preeserving.

Gerhard "When In Doubt, Try Everything" Paseman, 2016.07.24.

Comment: Can you give a specific example of an operator for $\oplus$?

Comment: No.  Average (a+b)/2 left and right distributes, but is not associative. plus itself associates, but does not distribute.  Your logsumexp and max and min are the ones I can think of.  I suspect there are noncontinuous examples ( think of a Hamel basis ) but I don't have anything explicit at present.  Gerhard "Having Everything Isn't Having Something" Paseman, 2016.07.24.